# Looking for a specific Harry Potter fanfiction: Snape adopts Harry and Draco

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I read it ages ago. I don't recall it being posted on ff.net or AO3. It was a story where Snape ends up fully adopting both Harry and Draco. Harry ends up with some prophetic dreams, is at one point blinded by Lucius poking needles in his eyes, for some time can only cast spells by saying the incantation in parseltongue. There was a fair bit of torture and some elements of self harm. I don't recall any particular romance elements or pairings. Was thinking about it recently, but can't recall the title or author. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fic you're looking for is *[A Year Like None Other](https://archiveofourown.org/works/742072/chapters/1382061)* by aspeninthesunlight, and I read it on AO3.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please [edit] your answer to explain why you think this is the answer (i.e. what details in this story match the ones given in the question).

Comment: There's hundreds of references to needles in that story; http://www.potionsandsnitches.org/fanfiction/viewstory.php?sid=1284&chapter=94