# Harry Potter Fanfic Where Harry Gets Adopted By Snape and Befriends Draco and Pansy

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, severus-snape, draco-malfoy

So before I had an AO3 account I was reading this fanfic where Dumbledore had told Harry (I think it was 3rd or 4th year) that if he left the Dursleys house that summer, it would endanger everyone he loved. So Harry lets himself get abused and malnourished and doesn't leave. Nobody comes to check on him, not the Weasleys, not Dumbledore, not Remus, no one. Except Snape.

Snape was assigned to guard the Dursley household and starts to get worried when he never sees harry. He goes and confronts Petunia and discovers Harry locked in a room barely conscious barely alive basically.

Snape confronts Dumbledore and gets stuck with the kid and at first he hates it. Like a lot. Then he sees how quiet and well mannered Harry is and the kid starts growing on him. (There's also this cute scene where Snape's house-elf takes them clothing shopping and Harry finds a bunch of crop tops that he likes)

(There's also this specific scene where the Malfoys and Snape and Harry all go strawberry picking and Harry and Draco get super competitive and it just feels very cozy and Lucius isn't a jerk)

Anyway, where I left off, Draco, Pansy, and Harry were being forced to live in the same house while Snape and Lucius do Death Eater things. They start becoming friends thanks to Mr. House-elf (I wish I remembered his name).

I've put in every tag combo I can think of and I cannot find this fic...

Comment: Duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242278/looking-for-a-specific-harry-potter-fanfiction-snape-adopts-harry-and-draco or https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246188/fan-fiction-where-snape-adopts-harry-potter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be [Just Stay There](https://archiveofourown.org/works/29144010/chapters/71549106)?

Harry is abused through neglect:

> The Dursley's had taken up a new tactic to torture him this summer. And boy was it thrilling. It wasn’t physical or anything, simply neglect.

Snape is the one to notice and rescue him in the first chapter.

Crop tops are mentioned in chapter 5:

> Then it struck him. They were crop tops.  
> The tiny shirts looked innocent enough, all of them ranging in colors. None of them purple though. Harry didn’t know what to think. Did he really want to try on these strictly feminine garments?

The House Elf is called Odin.

Competitive strawberry picking in chapter 14:

> To prove that he was now definitely focusing on the task, Draco began to speed up his movements. Quickly scuttling down the row, only picking a few berries from each bush before moving on. Potter noticed what he was doing and also hastened his task. Soon they were racing down the aisle. Their hands solely focused on the berries, and their eyes alternating between their opponent and the berries.

Found with search 'harry potter snape "crop top" site:archiveofourown.org'